# Twitter bootstrap change icon on collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsable element which contains tabs, where the collapsable element has an icon (icon-arrow-down) at the left side of the header text. When you collapse this element the icon changes to icon-arrow-up. It works great, but, when I change between tabs, the icon changes too.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6R44/

```
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <span class="icon-arrow-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseH" id="collapseP"></span>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </h3>
    <div id="collapseH" class="collapse in">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ic_tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#paragraph1" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph2" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph3" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="ic_tabsContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="paragraph1">
                content 1
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph2">
                content 2
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph3">
                content 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#collapseH').on('show hide', function(e){
        $('#collapseP').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up icon-arrow-down', 200);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a CSS-only solution. Change your toggle to this:

```
<span class="arrow-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseH" id="collapseP">
    <span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
    <span class="icon-arrow-up"></span>
</span>
```

Add this CSS to change the icon based on the collapsed state:

```
.arrow-toggle .icon-arrow-down,
.arrow-toggle.collapsed .icon-arrow-up {
    display: inline-block;
}
.arrow-toggle.collapsed .icon-arrow-down,
.arrow-toggle .icon-arrow-up {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7zvxa/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Best answer of the bunch -- Thanks.

Comment: when setting the class from `class="collapse in"` to `class="collapse"`, the incorrect icon is displayed. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zvxa/119/

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your selector from this:

```
$('#collapseH').on('show hide', function(e){
```

To this:

```
 $('#collapseP').on('click', function(e){
```

Your `#collapseH` is wrap all the tabs HTML, so when you click one one of the tabs you also clicks on `#collapseH`. So i change the selector to be fire only when the users clicks on the arrow itself `#collapseP`.

Use this

```
$('#collapseP').on('click', function(e){
            $('#collapseP').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down , icon-arrow-up', 200);
});
```

[See Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6R44/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the `show` event is fired when you click the tabs. If you add a check for the id being equal to collapseH before switching the arrow that should fix it. Here's a fiddle doing that.

http://jsfiddle.net/m6R44/3/

```
$('#collapseH').on('show hide', function (e) {
    //if($(e.target).attr("id") != "collapseH")return;
    if(!$(this).is(e.target))return; // from Arun P Johny
    $('#collapseP').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up icon-arrow-down', 200);
});
```

Comment: Seems random that it affects the outer element of the tab though. Is the event bubbling up maybe?

Comment: Thank you too, I've used @silagy's codes. They both works but his seemed to me simpler than yours.

Comment: @Smguy9 no problem. I did notice that when you spam the arrow it's state can get screwed up when you bind to the click method.

Comment: @sissonb Yeah, you're right, I just noticed it. I think I might use yours :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of event bubling

```
$('#collapseH').on('show hide', function(e){
    console.log(this, e.target, e.currentTarget)
    if($(this).is(e.target)){
        $('#collapseP').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up icon-arrow-down', 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).is(e.target))` nice